Program only prints the first few lines of the input file
In multiple compilers it prints only 7 lines from the file but there are MANY more lines but logically and syntax-wise the code looks good to me. Am I missing something? At first I thought it was the compiler but now I feel like there could be something wrong with my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Employee { // employee class
public:
    int employeeId;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string phoneNumber;
    string emailAddress;
    double salary;

    Employee(int id, string first, string last, string phone, string email, double sal)             // employee class constructor 
        :employeeId(id), firstName(first), lastName(last), phoneNumber(phone), emailAddress(email), salary(sal) {}

    void display() { // used to display an object of the employee class
        cout << "Id: " << employeeId << ", Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName
            << ", Phone Number: " << phoneNumber << ", Email: " << emailAddress
            << ", Salary: " << salary << endl;
    }
};


class Node { // class for each node of the linked list 
public:
    Employee* info;
    Node* next;

    Node(Employee* emp) : info(emp), next(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList { //the link list class itself 
private:
    Node* head;
public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {} // constructopr that initializes the list with no contents (empty)

    void insert(Employee* emp) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(emp);
        if (head == nullptr || head->info->employeeId >= newNode->info->employeeId) {
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            Node* current = head;
            while (current->next != nullptr && current->next->info->employeeId < newNode->info->employeeId) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            newNode->next = current->next;
            current = current->next;

        }
    }


    void display() { // function that displays the nodes of the link list 
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            current->info-> display();
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node* next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
};

// Now that all three classes are created and the functions needed with them, 
// we can now read from the file and add the employees to the linked list 
void readFile(const string& filename, LinkedList& list) {
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << endl;
        return;
    }

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        int id;
        string firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress;
        double salary;
        ss >> id >> firstName >> lastName >> phoneNumber >> emailAddress >> salary;
        Employee* emp = new Employee(id, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, salary);
        list.insert(emp);
    }
    file.close();
}
int main() {
    LinkedList list;
    readFile("Week 1-employeeDataset_Project 1.txt", list);
    list.display();
    return 0;
}

A sample line from the input file looks like this.
12690 Glynis Filipson 539-917-2209 gfilipson56@liveinternet.ru 105401.55

I believe the main issue if anything may lie in the read file function (above).

The code you've shown doesn't print anything. Please provide a [mcve]

the body of the question was update with the minimal reproducible version

What are the results from using the debugger?  Always draw linked lists when stepping through your code.

the debugger gives me no feedback, im not 100% sure what to look for in the debugger i just really use it to ensure the code runs properly, and the code outputs 7 lines that are in the correct order it just stops there and does not show the rest of the output

Now you've left out the insert function and the code that reads from the file, so the code you've shown still doesn't output anything. And what are the contents of the file?

the debugger gives me no feedback That is not its job / purpose. A debugger has no idea what you program is supposed to do so it can't give feedback.  Instead you are supposed to step through your code line by line in the debugger looking at the variables and flow after each individual statement is executed until you see some behavior you didn't expect.

the contents are a list of employee id names phone numbers email addresses and their salaries. all not reall individuals so i can post an example if needed

Please edit your post with a sample of the input data.

Post is edited thomas!

I was able to input the entire code to the post now

Too many pointers.  The Node class can use an Employee instance and not a pointer to an Employee.  The pointer is not necessary and makes your program more complicated.

Overload operator>> for your Employee class.  This will simplify your input loop.

You're going to need a copy constructor for Employee and Node.  Search the internet for "c++ rule 3/5/0".

"At first I thought it was the compiler." This should never be your first reaction when the program doesn't work as expected. Even very experienced C++ programmers only start to question whether it's an issue with the compiler after sufficient debugging. "It is always your fault."

Your insert function is wrong. In the else you have:
Node* current = head;
while (current->next != nullptr && current->next->info->employeeId < newNode->info->employeeId) {
    current = current->next;
}
newNode->next = current->next;
current = current->next;

At the end of this nothing in the linked list points to newNode, meaning it wasn't actually inserted. I can't test this right now, but I believe the last line should instead be
current->next = newNode;

(which is similar to the body of the if, but with current->next instead of head)

oh boy Kevin that was it!!!!

Must be the name! you are a god send
